# Preserve JQuery fullCalendar when navigating back to the page using vue.js or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

I have a calendar function that gets and sets a chosen start date, which works ok.

However when navigating away from the page and back to the previous page. How do I preserve the calendar on the day/month chosen when its beyond the present month. e.g. We are now in January, but if I navigate away to feb or march and navigate back, it defaults back to january.

Here is my code

```
 var fullDate = new Date();
 var newdate = new Date(fullDate);

 newdate.setDate(newdate.getDate() + 90);

 $('div[data-type="datepicker-coverStartDate"]').fullCalendar({
       dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
         if (moment(date).isSameOrAfter(moment().startOf('day'))) {
           $('.fc-state-highlight').removeClass("fc-state-highlight");
           $(this).addClass("fc-state-highlight");
           $('div[data-type="datepicker-coverStartDate"]').datepicker("setDate", $('#inpCoverStartDateActual').attr("value"));
           onDatePickerChanged('coverStartDate', date.toLocaleDateString("en-gb"));
         }
         if (date >= newdate) {
           $(this).removeClass("fc-state-highlight");
           $(this).addClass("fc-state-disabled");

         }
       }
```

and html input and calendar field

```
<input type="hidden" id="inpCoverStartDateActual" 
  v-bind:value="coverStartDate"
  name="@(NameOf<TellUsAboutYourHomeViewModel>.Full(basePropertyName, m => m.CoverStartDate))" 
  value="@(Model.CoverStartDate == DateTime.MinValue ? "" : Model.CoverStartDate.ToString(" dd/MM/yyyy"))" />
<div id="inpCoverStartDate" 
  value="@(Model.CoverStartDate == DateTime.MinValue ? "" : Model.CoverStartDate.ToString(" dd/MM/yyyy"))"
  data-type="datepicker-coverStartDate" 
  data-vue-data="coverStartDate" 
  type="text">
</div>
```

Comment: Vue and jQuery have no business together. Use Vue, OR use jQuery, but not both together... If you do, well, it will happen exactly this: the two libraries playing poorly together, and you trying to find workarounds to make things work somehow.

Comment: Unfortunately its a project I inherited. I think the previous dev, was learning vue. And introduced it in this project. Which I have now inherited. The Jquery calendar has given me so much headache.

Comment: Well I believe you, because Vue redraws the DOM, erasing everything jQuery does, and cancelling jQuery event listeners. So, having these two playing together is hell. You'll spend all your time trying to find hacks and workarounds.